# How to run/install wkhtmltopdf in php-buildpack (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

i want to use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) in my php application.
therefor i added `wkhtmltopdf` to my apt.yml file and hoped that everything will work...

...unfortunately, it doesn't.

everytime i run `wkhtmltopdf google.ch output.pdf` i get the following error:

`wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

does anybody know how to setup `wkthtmltopdf` correct in the php-builtpack of cloud foundry?

Comment: For now I use the static builded https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 composer dependency...

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- You are missing shared libraries dependencies. You'll need to add those to `apt.yml` so they get installed as well. It looks like [libgl1-mesa-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgl1-mesa-dev) might be what you're missing. There could be others though. If you run `ldd wkthtmltopdf`, you can see a list of all the dependencies & what's missing.
- The dependencies are installed, but they're not found when you try to run `wkthtmltopdf`. If you're running `cf ssh` to go into an app container so you can run `wkthtmltopdf` this might be the issue. Try running `cf ssh "<app-name>" -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"` instead. Otherwise, you need to manually `source` the `.profile.d/*` scripts. Buildpacks set env variables in these scripts and they often indicate where shared libraries can be loaded.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, we already use the `cf ssh "<app-name>" -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"` command to open the ssh connection.
I have added `libgl1-mesa-dev` to my `apt.yml` and can see it gets installed during `cf push` but the error of wkhtmltopdf still presists...
When I run `ldd /home/vcap/deps/0/bin/wkhtmltopdf` only `libgl.so.1` is not found.

Do you have another idea how to install the missing lib?

Comment: If you know `libgl.so.1` is installed but `ldd` is not seeing it, then there's probably an issue with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You might need to adjust that. Your solution is probably better though, there's a static binary available so just use that.